# Conscientious reject option to already approved edit

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, suggested-edits

When you reject an edit that has already been approved, you get an orange box telling you that it has already been approved.

[image: Edit Reject Box]

Now, clicking on the **the post** link appears to take you out of the queue, and attempting to click reject again just brings it back, and sometimes I don't want to make further edits, because sometimes the suggested edit was just a sideways edit to a non-problem post, and I don't want to stack more edits that don't need to be there.

If you do click on "improve" you might not be able to actually improve the post.  The following post is such an example where the editor left a comment on the post after the fact.

[Using forever with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524716/using-forever-with-node-js/6525407#6525407)

when I clicked on "edit(1)" there was already an edit in the queue, which I clicked reject on, but there wasn't an apparent way for me to actually remove the invalid edit.

Now, I understand that clicking reject in these situations might not actually have any effect, but I would like the option to exist, just so that I can conscientiously disapprove of the edit.

Comment: There were *2* suggested edits: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1079087 and http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1079063, both approved (oh horror, that last one should have been rejected). That's why you were confused here, I think.

Comment: If you could vote on an edit after the action was taken (even if it did nothing) and it was recorded it could potentially be confusing on the suggested edit page.  You'd need some way of visually indicating the vote was "too late".

Comment: I've encountered this before, and found the simplest solution is just to go to the post and roll back the edit.

Comment: This is especially annoying when the edit is approved 3-2 just seconds before you try to add the third reject vote. Sigh!! Perhaps we could have a rule about a stable result for at least 10 seconds before the majority is decided?